# How do I change command arguments ($1, $2) to integers?

Tags: scripting, terminal

I've got several arguments (`$1 $2`) to a script from the command line.

I'd been trying to test them, to make sure that the values entered weren't junk:

```
if [ $1 ]; then
    INPUT=$1
if [[ -n ${INPUT//[0-9]/} ]]; then
```

Ie: I'm trying to make sure that `$1` is not empty, and composed of 0-9 (digits), ie someone didn't type `script string more_strings` or a plain, unargumented `script` instead of something like `script 12 321`

But then trying to treat `$INPUT` (I also tried $1) as an integer:

```
if [ $INPUT -gt 100 ]; then
    INPUT=100
fi
```

Failed, and via echo testing, it looks like I've got a string (even though I used gt - which I thought meant to evaluate it as an integer?), and I'm not sure how to make it/evaluate $1 as an integer?

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/054

Suggests I do this:

```
if [[ $1 != *[!0-9]* ]]; then
```

But I don't understand what's going on in there.  Not equal to not 0-9???  Why *?

This looked interesting:

```
declare -i $1
```

But seems to permanently change $1? until reassigned?

**I'd like to know how to test my inputs, to make sure they're either A) strings or B) numbers/integers - and then how to use them from within my script (or how to convert them).  Preferably with an explanation.**

I've tried doing some searches of prior questions, and I'm obviously searching on the wrong terms - as this seems like a very rudimentary thing that I've forgotten how to do/should have already been answered somewhere else.

Didn't find it here, either:

https://ss64.com/bash/test.html

Maybe bedtime is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Within `[[ .. ]]`, the `=` operator is actually a pattern match, so `[[ $1 != *[!0-9]* ]]` tests if the value of `$1` does not match the pattern `*[!0-9]*`.

The patterns used here are the same as those for filename expansion, so `*` matches any character, and `[abc]` any character between the brackets, and `[!abc]` or `[^abc]` any character *not* between the brackets (excluding the initial `!` or `^`). In effect, that tests if `$1` contains some character that is not a digit from `0` to `9`.

---

`declare -i var` would mark the variable `var` as an integer variable: assignments to it would be interpreted as in an arithmetic context, so `declare -i a; a=3+5; echo $a;` would output `8`. But you can't use that on a positional parameter, like `$1`. Instead `declare -i $1` would take the string contained in `$1` and use *that* as a variable name. (Note that there's no `$` in `declare -i a` above.)

You can't really use `declare -i` to test if something is a number, as strings in arithmetic context are taken as variable *names*. This isn't an error: `declare -i a; b=1+2; a=b; echo $a;`. Instead, it prints `3`, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Checking to see if there is input, and then if it is numerical (of 1 or more digits), I used this [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

`if [ $2 ]; then
 INPUT=$2
 if [[ $INPUT = +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then`

This appears to be working to test for non-numerical input:

`if [[ -n ${INPUT//[0-9]/} ]]; then`

Answer (score 0):

Not a nice explanation like from ilkkachu

But you can try this way

```
[ ! -z $1 -a $1 -eq $1 ] 2>/dev/null && echo "integer $1" || echo "not integer $1"
```